# Spring Data Elasticsearch changeStream feature (like mongo changeStream)

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, changestream

Do Spring Data Elasticsearch has changeStream feature, like mongo? I'm trying to get data changes. I'm dealing with the following scenario:
We create a foo object. This foo object can be updated by multiple users. The changes need to be pushed to the UI.
In mongo you can use ReactiveMongoTemplate changeStream method.

The current Mongo implementation (Kotlin)

```
        val options = ChangeStreamOptions.builder()
            .filter(Aggregation.newAggregation(Foo::class.java,
                                               listOf(Aggregation.match(
                                                       Criteria.where("foo_id").`is`(
                                                               6)))
            )).returnFullDocumentOnUpdate().build()

    return reactiveMongoTemplate.changeStream("foo", options, Foo::class.java)
            .map { it.body }
            .doOnNext {
                print("foo update found $it")
            }
            .doOnError { print("Error") }
```

Comment: Please add your code into the question. That might be helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't have code for Elasticsearch implementation but I have Mongo working implementation.